# Getting Unicode Error when looping through tags and writing XML

Tags: python, xml, iteration, elementtree

I am trying to write out some XML that does have some special characters.  The place where I am running in trouble is when I iterate through a list of tags to create several elements called tag.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import xml.etree.ElementTree as xml

reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
```

Snippet of code:

```
    check = (video['tags'].split(', '))
    x=len(check)
    y=x-1
    for i in xrange(0,y):
        tagger = xml.SubElement(doc, 'field', name="tag")
        s=check[i]
        tagger.text = s.encode('utf-8')
```

The problem is when I try to write:

```
output = open(file_name,'w+')
tree = xml.ElementTree(add)
tree.write(output)
output.close()
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "xml_breakup3.py", line 108, in <module>
    tagger.text = s.encode('utf-8')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 0: invalid start byte
```

When I run my code without this snippet it writes the xml without a problem.  If I make tagger.text = any kind of string(i.e. '99') it writes fine. If I make the loop go from 0 to 3 it works.  It is only when I try to iterate through the whole list that I get an UnicodeDecode Error

when I try:

```
    check = (video['tags'].split(', '))
    for ta in check:
        tagger = xml.SubElement(doc, 'field', name="tag")
        tagger.text = ta
```

I get this:

```
     Traceback (most recent call last):
       File "xml_breakup3.py", line 172, in <module>
         tree.write(output)
    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 821, in write
    serialize(write, self._root, encoding, qnames, namespaces)
    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 940, in _serialize_xml
     _serialize_xml(write, e, encoding, qnames, None)
    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 940, in _serialize_xml
    _serialize_xml(write, e, encoding, qnames, None)
    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 938, in _serialize_xml
    write(_escape_cdata(text, encoding))
    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1074, in _escape_cdata
    return text.encode(encoding, "xmlcharrefreplace")
```

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xba in position 0: invalid start byte

Comment: Are you getting Unicode back when you parse the XML?

Comment: I used type(tags[i]) and it said str. Is there another test I should do?

Comment: @RocketDonkey Yes I'm getting Unicode back when I parse the XML.

Comment: Sorry, missed your first post - posted a potential answer, but happy to keep brainstorming if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try removing the `str` from in front of the piece you are encoding. When you use `str`, you are converting what I assume is Unicode into a string, which you are then trying encode. If you instead leave it as Unicode and decode directly, it should work:

```
>>> s = u'\xba'
>>> print s
º
>>> s.encode('utf8')
'\xc2\xba'
>>> str(s).encode('utf8')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#30>", line 1, in <module>
    str(s).encode('utf8')
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xba' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: @user1495088 And just to double-check, you are sure you are getting Unicode back?

Comment: how do I check for sure? I took the xml I generated (without the tags) and I was able to upload it to another application with no problem.  It had all of the special characters displayed properly. Is there another test I should do.

Comment: @user1495088 Alright, another question - what happens when you do no special encoding at all and say `tagger.text = s`? What is the error you receive, either there or when writing to the file?

Comment: @user1495088 Unrelated to the problem at hand, but when you do your iteration, I would suggest simplifying it to `for item in check`, and then referencing `item` instead of `check[i]`. I'll set up some testing on my end to see if I can duplicate the problem.